# Usage of からな at the end of a sentence

Tags: meaning

> どうした、反撃はしないのか？
>
> そう言うならさせてくれ！
>
> 冗談を言うな。お前は隙を見せると的確に狙ってくるからな
>
> さすがにずっと相手をしてるだけあってよく分かってるなあ。隙は見せてくれそうにないか。しかたない

As we all know many a time in the Japanese language things are left out because they are left for the listener/reader to fill in the blanks and guess what's being said without being directly told, or because it's "obvious".

Occasionally you would sometimes see the part that would come after から in a small sentence before a sentence that ends in it. But, in this case that isn't what is going on. Is the rest of it just not being said because it's "obvious" e.g.  お前は隙を見せると的確に狙ってくるから隙を見せないように努力している

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways of interpretation:

1. Suppose that `隙を見せる` = `反撃をさせる`, and the full sentence is `お前は隙を見せると的確に狙ってくるから、反撃はさせない`
2. Nothing is omitted. `からな` is a conversational element, like "you know why".

I have no means to tell which one is correct with the given context.